# Thickness of a 3d print general purpose plastic/PLA 230 V ~ isolator?

Tags: electrical-engineering, 3d-printing, lighting

I'd like to design a minimal thin light switch which holds an illuminant with standardized socket, e.g. E14, E27, and has itself such a socket to be screwed in a support and a switch which will be very small and distant from the thread and socket. Apart from the switch the object should be 3d printable with PLA for the thread and socket and the conductive parts will be printed as well or mounted after the print.

Now there's the question about the thickness of the PLA support at the buttom where the ground and phase are isolated against each other. I found no information which material is used in average sockets and which criteria it has to fulfill.

Answer (score 1):

Your major gotcha in this is probably thermal rating which is not going to be exactly wonderful with a PLA part.

Also, a lamp does not connect between ground a phase (except in weird circumstances), it connects between phase and neutral both of which are viewed as live current carrying conductors.

There is a reason most electrical accessories are made from a thermosetting material!